# How to Calculate Instability and Abstractness

Tags: dart

Does anyone know the value for Dart event loop architecture's Abstractness and Instability?

Thanks.

Comment: This is a big secret of Dart Team.

Comment: https://www.dartlang.org/articles/event-loop

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you look into the source?

https://code.google.com/p/dart/wiki/GettingTheSource